# Show UIAlertView only on initial startup

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I want my app to display an alert view the first time someone uses my app, and the second time, it wont appear. I've searched around, but cant figure it out. I'm using swift.

Here's my alertview method:

```
var alertView = UIAlertView()
alertView.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
alertView.title = "Information"
alertView.message = "Pinch the screen to scroll."
alertView.show()
```

Comment: You need to create some boolean flag and store it for example to NSUserdefauls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserdefaults()

if (userDefaults.valueForKey("alertViewShowedFirstTime") == nil) {
    // alertview code
    }
```

Then add this piece of code

```
 userDefaults.setValue("showed", forKey: "alertViewShowedFirstTime")
 userDefaults.synchronize()
```

I wrote it on the fly so it may not be error free but that's the main idea.
Just store in `NSUserDefault` that you already showed it once.

Comment: Thanks! Only had to show what "userDefaults" was by calling it:
    let userDefaults = NSUserfefaults.standardUserdefaults()

Answer (score 1):

You need to create some boolean flag and store it for example to NSUserdefauls. First time boolean going false.  Then you showing your alert, then you should make boolean true and store it to ns userdefaults. Always check your bool var from nsuserdefaults if it's true or false.

Comment: Thanks! Great to understand it, makes it a bit easier for me :)